# Maven execute doesn't work with TestNG.xml

Tags: java, selenium, maven, automation, testng

Hey guys I got issue by execute with maven on my project.

I posted what maven telling me when I'm trying to execute with him, XML itself does work but nothing else.so I need some help and I hope someone knows to handle it.

```
    <dependencies>

       <!--  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.30</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-edge-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.stephenc.monte</groupId>
            <artifactId>monte-screen-recorder</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

       <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.experitest</groupId>
            <artifactId>appium</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-path</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.24</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

and the profile of the build is

```
     <profiles>
            <profile>
                <id>web</id>
                 <build>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.14.1</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <includes>**/*Tests.java</includes>
                                <suiteXmlFiles>
                                    <suiteXmlFile>testNGWeb.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                                </suiteXmlFiles>
                                <argLine>
                                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                                </argLine>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>
            </profile>
        </profiles>
```

when I'm trying to use mvn test -Pweb it just makes it

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< org.example:FinalProject >----------------------
[INFO] Building FinalProject 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ pom ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.092 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-05-07T20:56:53+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

TestNgWeb.xml file is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Web Suite" parallel="false">
    <test name="Web Tests">
        <parameter name="PlatformName" value="web" />
        <classes>
            <class name="sanity.RedditWeb" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: I tried with 
"<suiteXmlFile>src/test/java/testSuites/testNGWeb.xml</suiteXmlFile>"
and it didnt work :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to set path to your xml from starting from src, ex:

```
<suiteXmlFile>src/test/java/testSuites/testNGWeb.xml</suiteXmlFile>
```

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the issue i had at my pom
pom
so i deleted it and run again,and its work.

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```